# How can i use material2 date picker?

Tags: android, material-components-android

Now material3 date picker seems like this:

[image: material3 date picker]

But i need to apply material2 date picker style:

[image: material2 date picker]

How can i do this? Maybe I searched badly, but I could not find this information on the Internet.